# power of four - utf-8 code?

Tags: math, utf-8

Does there exist a utf8 code for x(4), functional for cross browser/os.

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts
^4 should be at U+2074 but can't get it to work (on xp).

Comment: For a commercial operating system like Windows XP, shouldn't you be asking your vendor?  `x⁴`, btw.

Comment: Expand on what you mean by "can't get it to work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, but your mileage may vary by font. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2074/browsertest.htm

If you want reliable cross-browser rendering of more complex maths, you'll need to use [mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/)